# Imagick vs GD colour issues on image uploads

Tags: images

So I am using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for my local environment and uploading high-res RGB images to this.

Using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` I can see my local environment is running **Imagick**.

[image]

Everything looks great on local dev.

---

After uploading the same images to my staging environment on the server. The colour is totally zapped from the images.

I ran `phpinfo();` on the server and it's running **GD** for the image processing library.

[image]

---

Now the issue we have with running **Imagick** on the server is that it runs across all wordpress installs on the server.

The results of running **Imagick** is that it was spanking memory consumption and causing uploads to stall and fail. Especially for larger images and bigger batch uploads.

Reverting to GD solves these problems but then we're experiencing zapped color results as show above.

---

Here is a example image below used in the example above:

http://dev.joshmoto.wtf/red-calipers-with-discs.jpg

Dimensions: **6000px x 4000px**
RGB Color Profile: **sRGB ICE61966-2.1**

---

This is 1 of a 1000 images the client is going to be uploading.

Is there any kind of solution for this because telling the client that they need to change image colour profiles or save for web is not ideal.

Any thoughts would be appreciated thanks.